# How much slower would be to cache JSON instead of ready HTML in simple blog-like articles

Tags: php, json, performance, caching

I've got a simple caching system that works like this:
1. Editor goes to the admin panel,
2. Enters the data,
3. The data is saved to MySQL (for good measure) and put in the HTML template.

The template itself is a part of my page where the article is presented (its like `<article>...</article>`). Saved in HTML as {id}.html

When user enters the page /articles/22/ I just `include()` the corresponding HTML page to the main template. Super simple.

But it's a little primitive IMO. And I started to wonder wouldn't it be better to store JSON with fields like title, content, tags and stuff and then parse this with PHP and put to template. It gives me a few benefits (like the possibility to put the data in other places in the template), but my first priority is speed.

So - my question would be: would it be noticeable slower to get JSON (pre-saved in text files), parse it with PHP and put into template than including pre-saved HTML file. I know there is nothing to wonder here if we talk about 100 request in the same time, but what if we talk about more? Or maybe my approach is not mature at all and I should stick to popular "user gets to the page, you check how long ago the cache file was created, you include it or get from SQL if it expired"? I don't like that. I just don't think there is any reason user should be involved in creating the cache files. The only time they change is when the editor makes some changes, so let him be the one who creates cache files.

Comment: Any time you are dynamically creating the html it'll be at least slightly slower.  Serving it statically would be faster.  By how much?  Probably not a huge difference, but would depend on how many hits you get and other factors.

Comment: I think the main question is how `include()` compares to `json_decode()`. And it's a very general question, you have to forget 'other factors' to even start wondering.

Comment: In general `json_decode()` is very fast, even when working with very large JSON objects.  `include()` is probably far faster than `json_decode()`.  Though, it's kind of like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: If the articles don't change often, your best bet is to generate the static HTML after each edit and serve that.  The intermediate way you store it before generating the static HTML (JSON/MySQL/etc.) doesn't matter in that case.  Only the editor will see any slow down there.

Comment: Both apples and oranges serves the same purpose in my case - getting my stomach full. ;)

Comment: The problem with static HTML is that I can't put the title in the `<title>` tag. Any way to solve this? Caching whole HTML page seems a little over the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Using read through caching will get you a long way. Basically, if an object (could be rendered HTML, json or whatever works in your flow), does not exist in the cache, you would read through to the database to build it, once built, you would store it in the cache.

If changes were made to the object, you could delete the cache and it would be rebuilt the next time it is requested.

As for a cache, you would probably want to use something like memcached, although apc could work pretty well too.

Comment: So you suggesting the standard approach where the user is involved in creating cache file. And you suggest to store whole HTML page (not just the article part) in static files?

Comment: Storing the entire HTML page depends on whether or not you have dynamic content, but you can store at least parts of it.

Comment: The page is pure static. I have to reconsider this approach though. Maybe I am trying to improve something that can't be improved.

Comment: If the page is pure static, you could save it to disk. Make sure you are then using a good webserver that can more or less serve it from memory instead of disk. (nginx is a good choice)